# Spring Boot, Parameter 1 of constructor in ...Service required a bean of type '...Mapper' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm getting **bean** not found error on Mapper. It was working for just user entity, then i added food entity (all same as user) now it shows error.

**Description:**

Parameter 1 of constructor in com.example.springmysqlelastic.service.impl.FoodService required a bean of type 'com.example.springmysqlelastic.mapper.UserAndFoodMapper' that could not be found.

**Action:**

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.springmysqlelastic.mapper.UserAndFoodMapper' in your configuration.

**UserAndFoodMapper.java**

```
package com.example.springmysqlelastic.mapper;

import com.example.springmysqlelastic.model.Food;
import com.example.springmysqlelastic.model.FoodModel;
import com.example.springmysqlelastic.model.User;
import com.example.springmysqlelastic.model.UserModel;
import com.example.springmysqlelastic.model.dto.FoodDTO;
import com.example.springmysqlelastic.model.dto.UserDTO;
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;

import java.util.List;

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface UserAndFoodMapper {

    UserDTO toUserDTO(User user);

    List<UserDTO> toUserDtos(List<User> users);

    User toUser(UserDTO userDTO);

    List<User> toUsers(List<UserDTO> userDTOS);

    UserModel toUserModel(User user);

    FoodDTO toFoodDTO(Food food);

    List<FoodDTO> toFoodDtos(List<Food> foods);

    Food toFood(FoodDTO foodDTO);

    List<Food> toFoods(List<FoodDTO> foodDTOS);

    FoodModel toFoodModel(Food food);
}
```

**FoodService.java**

```
package com.example.springmysqlelastic.service.impl;

import com.example.springmysqlelastic.mapper.FoodMapper;
import com.example.springmysqlelastic.mapper.UserAndFoodMapper;
import com.example.springmysqlelastic.model.Food;
import com.example.springmysqlelastic.model.dto.FoodDTO;
import com.example.springmysqlelastic.repo.IFoodDAO;
import com.example.springmysqlelastic.service.IFoodService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class FoodService implements IFoodService {

    private IFoodDAO foodDAO;
    private UserAndFoodMapper foodMapper;
    //private final FoodMapper foodMapper;
    
    @Autowired
    public FoodService(IFoodDAO foodDAO, UserAndFoodMapper foodMapper) {
        this.foodDAO = foodDAO;
        this.foodMapper = foodMapper;
    }


    @Override
    public FoodDTO save(FoodDTO foodDTO) {
        Food food = this.foodDAO.save(this.foodMapper.toFood(foodDTO));
        return this.foodMapper.toFoodDTO(food);
    }

    @Override
    public FoodDTO findById(Long id) {
        return this.foodMapper.toFoodDTO(this.foodDAO.findById(id).orElse(null));
    }

    @Override
    public List<FoodDTO> findAll() {
        return this.foodMapper.toFoodDtos(this.foodDAO.findAll());
    }


}
```

Comment: UserAndFoodMapper is 1) an interface and 2) not a spring bean. Where is the implementation?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli impl file is generated by spring. There was 2 files, usermapper and foodmapper, here is the screenshot (i cant show current one cuz of not building) https://i.ibb.co/NrqtkYh/image.png

Comment: Are you using `MapStruct` ?

Comment: Is there only `UserAndFoodMapper ` not loaded? Or all mappers?

Comment: yes mapstruct @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks

Comment: @NasibullohYandashev yes there is one mapper for 2 entity. usermapper was working. then i added food entity and foodmapper then it broke. so i merged to one file according to my readings. now asks for bean.

Comment: so no one help?

Comment: where you able to resolve the issue @emretosunkaya

Answer (score 1):

upon adding these dependencies, i was able to resolve the issue.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mapstruct/mapstruct-processor -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mapstruct/mapstruct -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Instead of mapstruct-processor dependency, we can go with the plugin as mentioned [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65922885/8374909)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add @Component annotation to mapper class.

Answer (score 0):

You can add mapStruct processor to your pom.xml

Comment: <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.Final</version>
</dependency>

l